# Maven Eclipse structure project

Tags: eclipse, maven

My need is to cretae a project whose structure is :
Java_resources/src/main/java
Java_resources/src/test/java

and all the web content is under:
/WebContent

I tried to first create an Eclipse Dynamic Web Project, but it only create:

/src  and
/WebContent

And when I create a Maven project, it only create

Java_resources/src/main/java
Java_resources/src/test/java

and no WebContent

Is there any way to have a structure respecting the Maven structure and the "Dynamic Web project" ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a maven project and convert it to a eclipse project using command line:

```
mvn eclipse:eclipse
```

In case you want a web tools project you can add an extra argument:

```
mvn eclipse:eclipse -Dwtpversion=2.0
```

Source: http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-eclipse-plugin/wtp.html

Comment: I tried but:  [ERROR] BUILD ERROR
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] The plugin 'org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-eclipse-plugin' does not exist or no valid version could be found

Comment: which version of maven are you using?

Comment: You can always download it manually from [link](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.maven.plugins/maven-eclipse-plugin)

Comment: I download the latest maven release (3..) I configure the 'settings.xml' (proxy issue), then I execute the given command: It's ok, it generate me the good structure...

Answer (score 2):

No, don't break convention. Use the [folder structure](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-standard-directory-layout.html) Maven dictactes in a WAR project type. Install m2eclipse, this will handle everything for you.